# What does $d$ stand for in this formula?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, notation, projectile, calculus

Context: I am building a tennis ball machine and am having trouble interpreting the following formula for the flight path of the ball. I know all of the other values in the formula but the source I am using doesn't explicitly state what d is. I think it may be either distance or delta, any ideas?

[image]

If it helps the other variables are:

m = mass

t = time

Cd = drag coefficient

P = air density

g = gravity acceleration

Vx,y,z = components of translational velocity

Wx, Wy, Wz, = components of rotational speeds

C1 = life force coefficient

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions on the site.  This method is the standard and allows for expressions to be searched for (using the site search function).  Images of equations and pages are very strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about things like $\frac{d}{dt}$? $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is meant to be interpreted as $\frac{d}{dt}$ of $x$. $x$ is a function on which, when $\frac{d}{dt}$ is applied, it gives another function. The two functions are related in the sense that the function $\frac{dx}{dt}$ represents the rate at which the function $x$ changes as time passes. If $x$ is distance, then $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is speed. Look up derivates. $d$ is not a variable, it's part of the notation for a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

"d" stands for derivative. It's close to what you refer to as "delta" above ie., $\Delta$ as in $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, but in the limit as these quantities become infinitesimally small. If you drew a graph of $x$ versus $t$, then the quantity $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ will be the gradient. Now think about wanting to know what the gradient is at any *instant* in time. This is what $\frac{d x}{d t}$ is. The instantaneous gradient.

In the equations you mention above, $\frac{d x}{d t}$ would represent the objects instantaneous velocity $v$, and $\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = \frac{d v}{d t} = a$ is the objects acceleration.